# Update Operation not working properly in MYBATIS and getting error

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

Hi Iam trying to do update operation in MyBATIS,but iam getting SQL syntax error exception,iam not able to understand where iam doing wrong someone suggest me

```
Temp.java
public class Temp{
private int id;
private String name;
private List<Sect> sect;
//setters and getters
}

Sect.java
Public class Sect{
private int id;
private int sid;
private String sname;
private String priority;
//setters and getters
}
```

and my DB table structure for Sect is

```
sid     sname    priority  id
```

now i wanted to update multiple rows in Sect table at a time and my DAO query i wrote is:

```
<update id="updateSects" 
parameterType="com.****.****.****.Temp"> 
<foreach item="element" collection="sect" separator=",">   
Update sect set sid=#{element.sid},sname=#
{element.sname},priority=#{element.priority} WHERE 
id=#{element.id}
</foreach>;
</update>
```

but iam getting error as below:
    ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You 
    have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
    Update sections set sname='trial3',sid='90',priority=1,u' at line 2

and in my Java Service i calls my dao.xml as:

```
Service.java
public void updateSects(Temp temp) throws exception
```

Can someone please tell me where iam getting error

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to code a batch update.  What you are doing here is not a batch update.  With this you are building a single SQL statement - potentially a very large statement. Some databases support this type of syntax, some don't.  It may work if you set `separator=";"`.

It is much better to use MyBatis' built in support for batch operations. Take a look at this page for details: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert